# while upgrading tensorflow to gpu version , it thowrs PermissionError

Tags: tensorflow

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line
>   215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line
>   784, in install
>       **kwargs   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345,
>   in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323,
>   in clobber
>       shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
>       with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\wheel\archive.py'

Answer (score 0):

Yea I think I had the same experience. Most likely you had tensorflow activated. Make sure you close all applications that use tensorflow and then upgrade.

EDIT: This is from personal experience. My advice may or may not work however I do want to make it clear that it is not an answer but merely a suggestion.

Comment: Is this an answer or a guess?

Comment: This is from my personal experience.

Comment: You might want to rephrase this as a helpful answer then.